# Нужны ли запятые в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, однородные-члены, перечисление

Спорим полдня с человеком по поводу следующего предложения:
**Сладких объятий вам в это уютное солнечное осеннее воскресное утро.**

Мне говорят, что запятые не нужны, поскольку идет перечисление неоднородных прилагательных, но мне интуитивно режет глаза их отсутствие. Поясните, пожалуйста.

Comment: Оппонент формально прав, но - перечисление слишком длинное (для некоторых), оттого и ждутся запятые

Comment: Каждое предложение в русском языке "тонируется", то есть мы должны прочитать его с учетом повышения и понижения тона, разбить на отдельные фразы, удобные для чтения. Безусловно, прочитать 4 неоднородных определений подряд сложно, но автор и не собирался этого делать. Именно поэтому он включает в ряд как однородные, так и неоднородные определения.  Предложение делится уже на три фразы, которые удобно прочесть: Сладких объятий вам в это уютное// солнечное// осеннее воскресное утро. Это  на тему "ждутся запятые"  с таким оригинальным названием.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно: Сладких объятий вам в это **уютное, солнечное** осеннее воскресное утро.

Первые два прилагательных являются **однородными,** так как раскрывают тему хорошего утра. Отметим также, что уютное ― это **метафора**, а метафоры, как правило, однородны с другими прилагательными.

Два последних прилагательных являются **относительными** и поэтому **неоднородны** по отношению к двум первым.

Comment: Большое вам спасибо!

Comment: Извините, нет тут однородности. И пусть это вкусовщина, но она не менее обоснована, чем ваша

Comment: В русском правописании нет вкусовщины, всё по  правилам. Почитайте Розенталь, §10. Однородные и неоднородные определения, пункт 3. http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=98#pp98

Comment: @LazyBadger "Получился уютный, солнечный, безветренный каменный дворик" (из Нацкорпуса)

Comment: "Макарова уложили на постель в уютной, солнечной комнате" (Максим Горький)

Comment: Как уст румяных без улыбки,
Без грамматической ошибки
Я русской речи не люблю.
Быть может, на беду мою,
Красавиц новых поколенье,
Журналов вняв молящий глас,
К грамматике приучит нас;
Стихи введут в употребленье;
Но я... какое дело мне?
Я верен буду старине.